is there a way to colour a row whenever a value is found when i launch a search
I have an excel file, each row contains data in four columns.
When I search for a specific data, i want the row that contain thar data to be coloured, and remain coloured even when i search for another value which the row that contain it turns coloured also and remain coloured and so until i finish the search process.
How can i do this ?
I tried this:
Add a helper column:
Insert a new column next to your data, let's say column E.
In cell E1, enter the formula:
=OR(F1="",COUNTIF($F$1:F1,F1)>1)
Fill this formula down for all rows in your data.
Set up Conditional Formatting:
Select your data range (A1:D[last row]).
Go to Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule.
Choose "Use a formula to determine which cells to format".
Enter this formula:
=$E1=FALSE
Click "Format" and choose the color you want for highlighted rows.
Click OK to apply the rule.
Use column F for searching:
When you want to search for a value, enter it in the corresponding row in column F.
The row will be highlighted based on your chosen color.
You can enter multiple search terms in column F, and all matching rows will remain highlighted.
Clear searches:
To clear all searches, simply clear column F.

What's the result of the thing you tried? What's wrong with it?

it didn't work for me

Find&Replace helps you:

Select the data range and perform Find&Replace for the first value:

Repeat Find&Replace for subsequent values:


Hints:

Ctrl+H to call Find&Replace.
Click "Options>>" to display format settings.
Leave "Replace with" blank.
To right from "Replace with" click "Format..." and select "Fill" tab.


I'm assuming your data is values and not text, but here's one approach:
Insert your search values in column E.
In column F, use this formula: =BYROW(E1:E10,LAMBDA(x,IFERROR(SMALL(IF(((A1:D25=x)),ROW(A1:D25),""),1),"")))
You can limit or expand your search range by editing E1:E10 in the formula (first argument of BYROW()).
Then select your data, and apply conditional formatting: =COUNTIF($F$1#,ROW())>0
You can choose to hide Column F;


Quick sidenote: this will only mark the first time a value is found.
